# Generate random resource ID's with prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, random, model, helper

I have a simple Rails 3 invoicing application with the following models:

```
Brand
Client
Invoice
```

A brand has many invoices, clients have many invoices and invoices belong to clients and brands. Basically the brand is the company creating the invoice, client is the recipient of the invoice and the invoice the the actual invoice.

I am trying to work out the best way of having a simple random reference number for each invoice that's prefixed by something unique per brand.

I'm thinking of adding a invoice_prefix to the brand table. Then the brands would each have a three digit prefix, such as `DAN-`.

What would be the best way of adding the brands prefix followed by a 5 digit random number to a column in the invoice table?

I'm open to suggestions of better ways of doing this!

The end result I would like is for each invoice to have a unique reference similar to `DAN-98372`.

I think the best way would be to add the prefix column to the brand table and then create an before_create action for invoices that inserts a random number after the brand prefix. I'm just not sure on the best way to do this.

```
before_create :generate_reference

private
def generate_reference
  self.invoice_number = self.brand.prefix
end
```

The above code correctly pulls in the brand prefix, but I'm unsure how to add a random 5 digit number afterwards.

I think something like `<%= rand(1000..9999) %>` would work, but I'm not sure how to add that to the brand prefix in the before_create.

I'm not very familiar with after_create methods so any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I thought that, but then decided against it as I don't want clients to know the number of issued invoices. Seems like a bad idea if they know how busy/quiet business is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

https://github.com/patdeegan/integer-obfuscator

or https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id

that way you can hide how many invoices you really have and it will be unique

Comment: https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id looks good but only appears to be for the id column and doesn't mention anything about prefixes.

Comment: I'm trying that now, I don't seem to be able to get the `self.id` when using either before/after create.

Answer (score 1):

From the provided info, its a case of polymorphic association. refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

In the code provided, u should call 'generate_reference' 'before_create' rather than 'after_create' since u want the assigned values to be saved. specifying 'after_create' will go infinite loop.

Comment: I've just realised the mistake in using after_create, thanks!

Comment: actually, ur method wont save the invoice number cause u havent specified self.save Anyway, u should never update self in after callbacks of same model.

Comment: It does seem to be saving the invoice number, even without the self.save.

Comment: cause its 'before_create'. it will perform the action before the object is created.

Comment: Can you get self.id when using a before_create?

Comment: id is assigned when object is saved/created. pls read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Generate random data resources

https://github.com/wemersonblend/fakejs